# Smallest possible perimeter of a quadriliteral inscribed in a rectangle

Tags: geometry

A rectangle $ABCD$ is given. Let the points $P$ on $AB$, $Q$ on $BC$,$ R $ on $CD$ and $ S$ on $AD$ be inner points of the sides of the rectangle.
For which positions of the points $P, Q, R \ and \ S$ does the quadrilateral $PQ\ RS$ have the smallest perimeter?

I tried mirroring the points to prove that the perimeter is always the same. As it turns out, the perimeter is always $≥2AC$ (the diagonal of the rectangle) but it doesn‘t stay the same.

[image: An illustration]

Comment: Yes and hence that is the minimum perimeter.

Comment: Btw it says square PQRS, it should say quadrilateral?

Comment: See if this helps https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3488403/a-quadrilateral-inscribed-in-a-rectangle

Comment: @MathLover I‘ve seen that post and tried the first answer

Comment: Midpoints is not the only solution. You can read thru my answer.

Comment: My solution [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3488735/718671) proves that this perimeter is greater than or equal to $2AC$ via repeated applications of the triangle inequality. It's easy to see equality will only be achieved whenever all of the triangles to which the inequality is applied are degenerate, which happens precisely when $PQRS$ is a parallelogram.

Comment: @URL I agree. That is precisely my point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have:

$$SD^2+DR^2=SR^2$$

$$RC^2+CQ^2=RQ^2$$

$$PB^2+BQ^2=PQ^2$$

$$AP^2+SA^2=SP^2$$

We sum up both sides, we get:

$(SD^2+SA^2)+ (DR^2+RC^2) +. . .=SR^2+RQ^2+PQ^2+PS^2$

Now consider $SD^2+SA^2$ from  the sum of LHS of above relations , we may write:

$$(SA+SD)^2=SD^2+SA^2+2SA\times SD$$

$SA\times SD$ is maximum if $SD=SA$, because $SD+SA$ is constant. In this case $SD^2+SA^2$ will be minimum, That is if the vertices of quadrilateral is on midpoints of sides of rectangle it's perimeter will be minimum.
Now we show that if in a parallelogram with sides a, b, c, d (a=c and b=d) $(a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2)$ is minimum then $(a+b+c+d)$ is minimum; we have:

$(a+b+c+d)^2=(2a+2b)^2=4(a^2+b^2)+8ab$

Since $a^2$ and $b^2$ and $ab$ are minimum therefore $(a+b+c+d)$ is minimum.

From geometric point of view the resulting parallelogram can be considered as  a transformed  rectangle when vertices move along rectangle sides. the perimeter is maximum when vertices of parallelogram are coincident on vertices of rectangle and becomes minimum when the vertexes of parallelogram are on midpoints and increases when  vertices continue moving toward adjacent vertices.

Comment: I don‘t quite understand, I‘m sorry. How would one sum up those equations? And how is $SD^2+SA^2$ the sum of the left-hand side?

Comment: @supermaxy4, I gave more details in my edit.

Comment: But minimizing the sum of squares of PQRS lengths is not the same as minimizing the sum of lengths of PQRS. As all sides of quadrilateral are same if their vertices are on the midpoints of the rectangle, the right side simplifies and hence it definitely is one of the solutions that gives min perimeter but it does not clarify that it is the only one.

Comment: @MathLover, I edited my answer and answered your comment.

Comment: I see a problem in how you arrive at a conclusion that perimeter is min when vertices are  on midpoints and increases when vertices move towards adjacent vertices of the rectangle. I do not contest that midpoints is a solution but it is not the only solution.

Answer (score 1):

Say we have a rectangle with length $AB = CD = a$ and width $BC = DA = b$ and a quadrilateral $PQRS$ inscribed as shown in the diagram. Say, $ \, AP = x, AS = y$.

[image]

We reflect point $P$ through both $DA$ and $CB$. So,

$PA = AP'$ and $PB = BP"$. Now $\triangle APS \cong \triangle AP'S$ and that does not change even if we slide point $S$ on line $DA$ up or down.
Same is the case with $\triangle BPQ \cong \triangle BP''Q$.

$RS + SP = P'S + SR \ge P'R$.

The equality occurs when we slide point $S$ on line $DA$ such that $S$ falls on line $P'R$. We do it similarly for point $Q$ such that

$PQ + QR = P''R$.

So, perimeter of quadrilateral reduces to $P'R + RP''$.

The base of the triangle $P'P''R = P'A + AP + PB + BP" = 2 (AP + PB) = 2AB = 2a$.

The height of the triangle is $b$.

Now we know that for a given area of the triangle (fixed base and height), isosceles triangle has the minimum perimeter (we can in fact show that using reflection too).

So, $P'T = P''T = a$. That gives $P'R = P''R = \sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ and hence the minimum perimeter of the quadrilateral is $2\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$.

We can also show that $AS = CQ, AP = CR$ and that PQRS is a parallelogram.

As $\triangle P'SA \sim \triangle PRT$, $\displaystyle \frac{AS}{AP'} = \frac{RT}{P'T} \implies \frac{y}{x} = \frac {b}{a}$. **Points P, Q, R, S must meet this condition ensuring parallelogram and for the quadrilateral perimeter to be minimum**.

So, $x = \frac {a}{2}, y = \frac{b}{2}$ is **definitely one of the solutions but is NOT the only solution**.

**EDIT:**

Here is a diagram of quadrilateral with min perimeter inscribed in a rectangle but its vertices not at the midpoints of the rectangle. Please note it meets the ratio condition I mentioned and the angles above (parallelogram) and hence works.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

By Optics Fermat principle that light takes minimum time during *reflection* i.e., when incidence/reflection angles will all be equal, we should have full symmetry with center points of sides as incidence/ bounce off points.

$$ L= \sqrt{(w-a)^2+(h-q)^2+...+...+...+...+...+...} $$

The bounding rectangle measures $(2w\times 2h )$. Partially differentiate the total length $L$ w.r.t variable deviations $(a,b,p,q)$ , equate to zero, so we can establish that  deviations vanish for a minimum total $L$.

[image]

Comment: Why is this necessary conditon? I can choose incidence and reflection points such that the sum of two adjacent sides is min without them being equal.

Comment: Sorry , now I have added an explanatory remark. Actually the Snell's Law in Optics is derived in this way.

Comment: But the point that I am making is that I can always have points E, F, G, H in a way such that $\angle HGD = \angle BGF, \angle GFB = \angle AFE$ without all $4$ of them being equal and minimizing the sum of the adjacent sides without vertices being at midpoints. See the diagram I have added at the end in my answer. Thank you.

Comment: @MathLover, to show that you have to apply analytic geometry.